# How to resolve MessageConversionException in spring-kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, type-conversion, spring-kafka

I have been using spring-kafka for my project and currently, I'm facing an issue.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.polubentcev.messenger.model.subscription.SubscriptionsRequest] for GenericMessage [payload={"userId":"4","pagination":{"offset":0,"quantity":10}}, headers={kafka_offset=23, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3817b042, kafka_correlationId=[B@13cf505b, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_replyTopic=[B@58355ff, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=07, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1548552030765, __TypeId__=[B@7480d2ef}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:144) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:283) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Such exception is thrown when a message arrives at my microservice.

Here is my configuration:

```
private final Map<String, Object> consumerProps;

public KafkaConsumerConfiguration(@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}") final String bootstrapServers,
                                  @Value("${kafka.consumer.group-id}") final String consumerGroupId) {
    this.consumerProps = Map.of(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers,
            ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId,
            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
            ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class
    );
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Pair<String, String>>>
kafkaSubscriptionListenerContainerFactory(final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Pair<String, String>, UsersSubscription> kafkaTemplate) {
    final DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Pair<String, String>> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            consumerProps, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>()
    );
    final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Pair<String, String>> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(cf);
    factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate);
    return factory;
}
```

It's very strange because it must work. I tried to resolve it on my own but wasn't succeed because didn't know where to dig deeper.

Could you help me with it?

BTW, I tried in debugger to convert the payload `String` using new `ObjectMapper<>().readValue()` and it works, also all `SubscriptionsRequest` contains `@JsonCreator` and all necessary things for deserialization.

WORKAROUND: I added a `SubscriptionsRequest(String str)` constructor where I build an instance using `ObjectMapper`. It works but it's ugly.

Comment: It's not clear how the JSON string would reach the listener adapter; I would expect a problem in the deserializer if the object couldn't be created. By the way, the `setReplyTemplate()` takes a regular `KafkaTemplate`. The replying template is used on the client side to send/receive; here, we're just sending the reply. Also, there is no need to configure the deserializers in properties when you explicitly add them to the consumer factory.

Comment: Please show your `@KafkaListener`.